# Get body of web page on address bar drag drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I need to pull information from a web site.  The user drags the address from IE to a C# win-form application.  The web page they are dragging is not accessible by the address alone, saving the page to a bookmark brings me back to a useless page.  How can I force a drag event to save the page to a local html file, and store that local file location in my win-form app?

Comment: I decided to put a web browser in the C# app then copy from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be useful to you:  [HTML5 Drag & Drop - Data Transfer Types](http://decafbad.com/2009/07/drag-and-drop/api-demos.html#data_transfer)

Comment: Unfortunately the text content is just the address of the link, and the html content is the address of the link.

Comment: You can set the value of the text content.. from the .js source: `.setData('text/plain', 'Hello world!');`

Comment: Note that you'll need to create a draggable object for the user, rather than having them drag the address.

Comment: I don't control the web page.  So I'm guessing this is not an option.

Comment: If you don't have control over the website and the link does not lead to the wanted information then the link is simply not enough information to get the website content you're looking for. If you really need to do this the way you described, you might consider writing an IE-plugin - but i'm not recommending that...